# Value attribute is missing after adding thymeleaf's tag th:field to input

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Here is my form, I have one input where value is 0. It works perfectly fine until I add `th:field="*{dishQuantityMap[__${dish.id}__]}"`.

```
   <div class="single-menu" th:each="dish : ${dishList}">
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/menu}" th:object="${order}" method="post">
            <button class="decrement"  onclick="stepperDecrement(this)">-</button>
                            <input
                             th:field="*{dishQuantityMap[__${dish.id}__]}"
                                    type="number"
                                    min="0"
                                    max="100"
                                    step="1"
                                    value="0"/>
           <button class="increment"  onclick="stepperIncrement(this)">+</button>
                <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-light mt-3 btn-lg">Confirm order</button>
        </form>
     </div>
```

After that - value just disappears. Here is what I see in my page.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually set the name/value/id like you're doing in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70834923/thymeleaf-how-to-make-thname-like-this) you asked, or you can set the value in your map for each dish to 0 in your controller.

```
for (var dish: dishList) {
  dishQuantityMap.put(dish.getId(), 0);
}
```