# Thymeleaf, how to make th:name like this?

Tags: thymeleaf

For this to work I neeed `th:name` to be `dishIdQuantityMap[dish.id]` ( for example, if dish has an id of 1 - `dishIdQuantityMap[1]`;
But how can this be implemented?

```
<div class="single-menu" th:each="dish : ${dishList}">
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/menu}" th:object="${order}" method="post">
       <input 
                                   th:value="0"
                                   th:name="!!!!"
                                   type="number"
                                   min="0"
                                   max="100"
                                   step="1"
                            />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Here is an example of OrderDto.

```
 public class OrderDto {
        private Map<Long, Integer> dishIdQuantityMap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Standard expression syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#standard-expression-syntax).

```
th:name="|dishIdQuantityMap[${dish.id}]|"
```

or

```
th:name="${'dishIdQuantityMap[' + dish.id  + ']'}"
```